# Change in state not reflecting in function in Next.Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-state

I have a functional component that renders out an array of products. I get the array of products from it's props and set it's state using `useEffect` and the `useState` hooks.

I am trying to implement a simple search filter function by taking the original array and
filtering it based on some conditions.

This component re-renders a few times because it's the items are loaded from an ajax call in the parent. The problem here is that even though the value of `originalItems` gets updated eventually, this doesn't reflect when the `handleFiltering` method is called. In this method, the value of `originalItems` is still an empty array.

Can someone please explain why the state of this variable isn't updated in this function? And is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```js
const ProductList = ({ items }) => {
  const [taggedWith, setTaggedWith] = useState("");
  const [queryValue, setQueryValue] = useState("");
  const [originalItems, setOriginalItems] = useState([]);
  const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOriginalItems(items);
    setFilteredItems(items);
  }, [items]);
  
  const handleQueryValueChange = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      setQueryValue(value);
      handleFiltering(value, taggedWith);
    },
    [taggedWith, handleFiltering]
  );
  const handleTaggedWithChange = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      setTaggedWith(value);
      handleFiltering(queryValue, value);
    },
    [queryValue, handleFiltering]
  );

// PROBLEM HERE
  const handleFiltering = useCallback(
    (filter, tag) => {
      // originalItems is still an empty array here. So as a result, the filteredValues 
      array is always empty. 
      const filtered = originalItems.filter((item) => {
        if ((!filter || item.title.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())) && (!tag || 
        item.tags.includes(tag))) return item;
      });
      setFilteredItems(filtered);
    },
    [originalItems]
  );

  return (
    <Page >
      <Card>
        <ResourceList
          items={filteredItems}
          loading={loading}
        />
      </Card>
    </Page>
  );
};


export default ProductList;
```

(Please note that I've omitted some code to reduce clutter. The values of `taggedWith` and `queryValue` are updated correctly, but the I've left out that piece of code)

Comment: Maybe try it without all the memoized callbacks? For sure you don't ned to memoize the first two, and I'd guess you don't need to memoize the third one either. You should be able to just define plain old arrow functions without the `useCallback`.

Comment: @David784 thank you so much! That seems to have fixed the issue! I did try using the `handleFiltering` function alone without `useCallback`, but that didn't solve the issue.  Not memoizing everything seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're overusing `useCallback`. Making a [memoized callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) can be helpful in certain limited circumstances where running your callback in very expensive. But you have to be very careful to make sure your list of dependencies is correct.

In your instance there is no reason to memoize `handleQueryValueChange` and `handleTaggedWithChange`, and these are probably causing your problem. They don't have either `items` or `originalItems` as a dependency, so they are not getting updated as a result.

The really important part is that the overuse of memoization means these functions are referencing an older copy of `handleFiltering`, which exists in a scope/context where `originalItems` is still an empty array.

Getting rid of all `useCallback`s is probably the best route...you can always add it back to `handleFiltering` if you start having performance problems and you find memoization helps.